# Kotlin generic collections as function parameter

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

In my Android app, I have a parent class named `FilterOption` which has 2 child classes named `UserFilterOption` and `BusinessFilterOption`.

```
abstract class FilterOption<T> {
    abstract fun match(filter: T): Boolean
}
```

The child classes implement this class and pass their `T` types, as expected. This is fine.

I have another function in my custom `View` class that takes a `Set<>` of these filters and does work on them:

```
interface FilterableView<T> {

    fun onFilterOptionChanged(filterOption: FilterOption<T>)

    private fun addFilter(menu: Menu, labelResId: Int, filterOptions: Set<FilterOption<T>>, filterOption: FilterOption<T>) {
        menu.add(labelResId).apply {
            isCheckable = true
            isChecked = filterOptions.contains(filterOption)

            setOnMenuItemClickListener {
                onFilterOptionChanged(filterOption)
                true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I define my Views like this:

```
class BusinessFragment : FilterableView<BusinessFilterType> {
   ....
}
```

But when I try to call this function in the `FilterableView` class, I get errors:

```
private fun addBusinessFilters(menu: Menu, businessFilterOptions: Set<FilterOption<T>>) {
    addFilter(
        menu, R.string.general_open, businessFilterOptions,
        BusinessFilterOption.BusinessType.Open  <-- ERROR HERE
    )
    addFilter(
        menu, R.string.general_closed, businessFilterOptions,
        BusinessFilterOption.BusinessType.Closed  <-- ERROR HERE
    )
}
```

ERROR:

```
Type mismatch.
Required: FilterOption<T>
Found: BusinessFilterOption.BusinessType.Open
```

This is the same for the other type ("Closed"), as well as all the other types on the `UserFilter`.

This is the definition of the BusinessFilters:

```
sealed class BusinessFilterOption : FilterOption<Business.View.BusinessModel>() {

    sealed class BusinessFiltersType(private val type: BusinessFilterType) : BusinessFilterOption() {
        override fun match(filter: Business.View.BusinessModel): Boolean {
            //check if match with open or closed
        }

        object Open : BusinessFiltersType(BusinessFilterType.OPEN)
        object Closed : BusinessFiltersType(BusinessFilterType.CLOSED)
    }
}
```

So what i'm trying to do is make the `addfilter` method generic so I can pass `UserFilterOption` and `BusinessFilterOption` to it, because they both inherit from `FilterOption<T>`, so I don't understand why the error is telling me I need to pass the parent class, when I'm passing the child class.

Can anybody help? Thanks

Comment: I noticed you edited your question based on my answer. Be aware users do not get notified of this! It's best to leave behind a comment, which they do get notified of. I'll edit my answer to reflect your changes, but note that the majority of it remains. Is there anything in it you don't understand/I should elaborate on?

Answer (score 0):

`T` of `addFilter` is defined in `FilterableView<T>`. This means that the type passed to `FilterableView` determines the valid parameters that can be passed to `addFilter`. For `BusinessFragment`, only `BusinessFilterOption` would be allowed.

Where is `addBusinessFilters` defined? This method seems counterintuitive given the generic `FilterableView<T>` you have defined prior.

> So what i'm trying to do is make the addfilter method generic so I can pass UserFilterOption and BusinessFilterOption to it

**Do not confuse generics with inheritance**, although you might be interested in [reading more about generic constraints](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html).

If that is what you want, you need polymorphism, and your view should be allowed to take any `FilterOptions<T>`. At the risk of not understanding your design considerations, you likely want to *not* make `FilterableView<T>` generic and instead make `addFilter` a generic method.

```
private fun <T> addFilter(
    ...,
   filterOptions: Set<FilterOption<T>>,
   filterOption: FilterOption<T>
) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only issue you have is with the declaration of your `BusinessFragment`. Your `FilterableView` interface takes in a `T` which is the same type as the `T` in your `FilterOption`.

Your `BusinessFilterType` classes are `FilterOption<Business.View.BusinessModel>`, so your `BusinessFragment` should be declared as `BusinessFragment<Business.View.BusinessModel>` rather than `BusinessFragment<BusinessFilterType>`.